# Use my server as a proxy to bypass blocked ports

Tags: proxy, port, dedicated-server

I cannot connect to some services (TS3, Mumble, Steam...) from my university because some ports are blocked. I was wondering, can I use my dedicated server as a kind of proxy? so I connect to my dedicated server on a allowed port (of my choice) and then the dedicated server connects to the service.

I am currently studying computer science and have good programming knowledge but almost no knowledge about networks and unix world. Could you guide me about which programs could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access and the services you require can make use of a SOCKS proxy, `ssh`'s dynamic port forwarding feature would be a very easy solution for this problem.

Open a SSH session on your client with the following command:

```
ssh -D 8080 <your server>
```

Now you can use `localhost:8080` as a proxy. For example, enter this address as a SOCKS proxy into the network configuration of your browser, and your browser should then be tunneled completely through your server.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN server and client do exactly what you want.